How to avoid NullPointerException(NPE)
Since we all know that few couple days ago there was a global outage (BSOD) because of the CrowdStrike updated which caused that global outage and the reason behind that was just an NullPointerException.
As a responsible Dev, how would you avoid this NPE? I know that we can check before performing action on object but it seems to be ugly syntax to me like if(thing != null)

There are approximately 27,132 ways of avoiding this. Putting them all in a Stack Exchange answer would be much too long.

you need to have a comprehensive testing strategy. Just checking for null is useless unless you know if the value is allowed to be null and what to do in that particular case. According to some reports there where only automated tests of the crowdstrike update, and these tests where buggy. This is clearly insufficient testing for such highly privileged code.

No, that didn’t happen at all. A null pointer exception happens when an attempt to use a null pointer is detected, and as a result the null pointer is not used but an exception thrown instead.
There was no null pointer. There was an invalid pointer which in Java for example would be harder to produce but would lead to a crash.
And the invalid pointer happened during the boot of a system. That’s a time that errors cannot be handled but are fatal. But an exception wouldn’t have helped, because the exception handler would have been in the exactly same situation.
We had code here that must either be correct or must crash. The only way to avoid this is to write correct code. This in turn is done by hiring competent developers, and using intensive testing, again done by competent testers.
And seriously, if you reject a solution (which wasnt a solution, as explained) because you don’t like the syntax, then consider that you might be in the wrong business.
